# Access denied to admin on custom module

Tags: 8, routes, users

I get access denied to admin user in my custom module. This is my routing yml file:

```
operatordb:
  path: operator-database
  defaults:
    _form: \Drupal\operatordb\Form\OperaDBForm
    _title: 'Operations over databases'
  requirements:
    _role: 'administrator+manager+superuser'
```

I have checked spaces and parameters. Users with role manager or role superuser can access to the form without problems and use it, but admin user (with role administrator - 1) get access denied. I don't know why It happens.
Some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to set requirements to a role. Create a permission, then assign that permission to roles. Use that permission as your requirement. If you insist on going with the roles route, then check that you've used the correct machine key for the role that is having troubles.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you said, I will change that permission to my own. But, despite of this, It's very strange what is happening with admin, and If _role is available, why not use it?

Comment: Using permissions is more dynamic, and will allow you to migrate your code between systems in the future. If you use roles, the role may not exist on the system in the future. On top of this, a permission will be bypassed by user 1 (all permissions are), whereas a role may not be (I haven't tested). Also, did you check the machine name of 'admin'?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. All listed roles in routing.yml file are machine names. As I said, It works good for the other roles. And administrator is the user 1. Thanks for your help.